# Simple Vandermonde Matrix with for loop

Tags: python, loops

This is a very simple question.My aim is to eventually create a Vandermonde matrix but first i need to:

Write a function that takes a real number  α  and an integer  n  as input, and returns a vector  v=(1,α,α2,…,αn−1)

so far i have:

import numpy as np

```
n =6
a= 3
for i in range(n):
    v = np.array([1, a**2, a**(n-1)])
print v
```

I get: [  1    9  243] which is not what i want. Please can you help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a *list comprehension*:

```
v = np.array([a**x for x in range(n)])
```

This is equivalent to:

```
v = []
for x in range(n):
    v.append(a**x)
v = np.array(v)
```